# How to make multiple choice games on python

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game which includes multiple choice questions. It will include the user choosing one of the three options to answer the question.
The options will change for every new question.

As I am new to python, I am confused and unsure on how to start. I am not able to make clickable text boxes. I am making this game on pygame.

In a pre-answered question: [How to ask 20 multiple choice questions on pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726334/how-to-ask-20-multiple-choice-questions-on-pygame) I would like some advice on how to create something like this. The code for this is in the link.

Below is an image on what @sloth has successfully managed to create.

[image]

So for my question, instead of the numbers as the options, my game will have different answers that change for every new question.

If you have any tips or can show me how to begin, it'll be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to use a GUI. Try one like tkinter or PyQt5

Comment: You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726334/how-to-ask-20-multiple-choice-questions-on-pygame/59729471#59729471)

Comment: @Pilot Dude- I’m trying to stay away from other applications like Tkinter if possible. Mainly because the rest of my game uses pygame as I can make a blank screen from there.

Comment: @hippozhipos & sloth- I looked into that and I tried using the code to get rid of the first scene which was the space bar to start. I don’t know how to get rid of that. If I can remove that it’ll help me a bit more. But the answer boxes in that screen are fixed but my answer boxes change for every question which is where I find it hard.

Comment: @Davina What do you mean by your answer boxes change? It would help if you showed the that handles it.

Comment: @hippozhipos I have updated my question with more detail to answer your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the game scene class, you could add something like choices.

```
 self.choices = ['x', '-', '*', '+']
```

I have never used `pygame.freetype` before but seems like the rendering text is done using

```
SimpleScene.FONT.render_to
```

So you can iterate over the choices and draw them

```
SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x+29, rect.y+29), str(self.choices[n]), 
pygame.Color('white'))
```

---

To have different options for different questions, you can expand the `self.choices` list to be a 2D list. Then iterate through that list and render them depending on what the current question is. Also looks like sloths original code does not adjust the size so rendering words would not work. So I have slightly modified the way boxes are rendered to fit words. Also I have added a comment called `#CHANGE` to show the changes that were made to the previous one.

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
import random

class SimpleScene:

    FONT = None

    def __init__(self, next_scene, *text):
        self.background = pygame.Surface((640, 480))
        self.background.fill(pygame.Color('lightgrey'))

        y = 80
        if text:
            if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
                SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)
            for line in text:
                SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (120, y), line, pygame.Color('black'))
                SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (119, y-1), line, pygame.Color('white'))
                y += 50

        self.next_scene = next_scene
        self.additional_text = None

    def start(self, text):
        self.additional_text = text

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
        if self.additional_text:
            y = 180
            for line in self.additional_text:
                SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (120, y), line, pygame.Color('black'))
                SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (119, y-1), line, pygame.Color('white'))
                y += 50

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    return (self.next_scene, None)

class GameState:
    def __init__(self, difficulty):
        self.difficulty = difficulty

        #CHANGE
        self.questions = [
            (" 4 _ 6 = 10 ?", 4),
            ("Which one is a fruit?", 2)
        ]
        self.current_question = None

        #CHANGE
        self.question_index = 0
        
        self.right = 0
        self.wrong = 0


    def pop_question(self):
        q = random.choice(self.questions)
        self.questions.remove(q)
        self.current_question = q

        #CHANGE
        self.question_index += 1
        
        return q

    def answer(self, answer):
        if answer == self.current_question[1]:
            self.right += 1
        else:
            self.wrong += 1

    def get_result(self):
        return f'{self.right} answers correct', f'{self.wrong} answers wrong', '', 'Good!' if self.right > self.wrong else 'You can do better!'

class SettingScene:

    def __init__(self):
        self.background = pygame.Surface((640, 480))
        self.background.fill(pygame.Color('lightgrey'))

        if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
            SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)

        SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (120, 50), 'Select your difficulty level', pygame.Color('black'))
        SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (119, 49), 'Select your difficulty level', pygame.Color('white'))

        self.rects = []

        #CHANGE
        for n in range(4):
            rect = pygame.Rect(50, (n * 70) + 100, 500, 50)
            self.rects.append(rect)


    def start(self, *args):
        pass

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
        n = 1
        for rect in self.rects:
            if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'), rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'), rect, 5)

            #CHANGE
            SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x+30, rect.y+15), str(n), pygame.Color('black'))
            SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x+29, rect.y+14), str(n), pygame.Color('white'))
            
            n+=1

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                n = 1
                for rect in self.rects:
                    if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        return ('GAME', GameState(n))
                    n += 1

class GameScene:
    def __init__(self):
        if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
            SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)

        self.rects = []
        
        for n in range(4):
            rect = pygame.Rect(50, (n * 70) + 100, 500, 50)
            self.rects.append(rect)

        #CHANGE
        self.choices = [['x', '-', '*', '+'], ["whatever", "apple", "whatever", "whatever"]] 

    def start(self, gamestate):
        self.background = pygame.Surface((640, 480))
        self.background.fill(pygame.Color('lightgrey'))
        self.gamestate = gamestate
        question, answer = gamestate.pop_question()
        SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (120, 50), question, pygame.Color('black'))
        SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (119, 49), question, pygame.Color('white'))


    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
        n = 0
        for rect in self.rects:
            if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'), rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'),
                             rect, 5)

            #CHANGE
            for i in range(len(self.choices)):
                if self.gamestate.question_index ==  i + 1:
                    SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x+30, rect.y+20), str(self.choices[i][n]), pygame.Color('black'))
                    SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x+29, rect.y+19), str(self.choices[i][n]), pygame.Color('white'))
            n+=1

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                n = 1
                for rect in self.rects:
                    if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        self.gamestate.answer(n)
                        if self.gamestate.questions:
                            return ('GAME', self.gamestate)
                        else:
                            return ('RESULT', self.gamestate.get_result())
                    n += 1

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0
    scenes = {
        'TITLE':    SimpleScene('SETTING', 'Welcome to the quiz', '', '', '', 'press [SPACE] to start'),
        'SETTING':  SettingScene(),
        'GAME':     GameScene(),
        'RESULT':   SimpleScene('TITLE', 'Here is your result:'),
    }
    scene = scenes['TITLE']
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        result = scene.update(events, dt)
        if result:
            next_scene, state = result
            if next_scene:
                scene = scenes[next_scene]
                scene.start(state)

        scene.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Bug was that the questions were being picked at random so the indices didn't align. Since the original code was not designed to have different choices, the class handling answer does not have access to the random variable controlling which question gets picked. So there isn't really any way to have random questions without sacrificing encaptulation. So I suggest just remove the randomness and pop the question directly i.e

Replace

```
q = random.choice(self.questions)
```

with

```
q = self.questions[0]
```

Its in `GameState` class in `pop_questions` method.

Comment: Thank you @hippozhipos! How would I add another question if the choices are different from the previous question? Would you have to repeat the code again because I'm confused on how to do so.

Comment: Why don't you just say leave the options as 1, 2, 3, 4 and just render some text underneath saying what each options means. Something like `1. +,  2. -,  3. *, `

Comment: @hippozhopos For my A-level we have to create a program which has enough scope. And I’m making four categories. There are three multiple choice questions in each category so the questions have to be different. It will be marked whether the project has enough scope, which is why I need to be able to change the three questions. I don’t want the questions to be kinda repetitive if you understand..? Is there any way I can make different options when the question changes?

Comment: @Davina Yea I get what you mean. I am doing my A level this year as well and I am exactly in the same position as you lol. I am kinda busy right now so I will update the answer in a bit.

Comment: @Davina I updated the answer but I just realised there a bug.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. I ran the code and didn't notice any bugs. Just one last question sorry, how can I get rid of the difficulty screen? I tried removing parts of the code before and it came up with a bunch of errors.

Comment: Don't swap them. They are in the right order. That way you can add as many questions as you want to. Look at the edit

Comment: Ok, just saw your edit once I asked the question. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 0):

You can use all sort of GUIs(graphical user interface), such as Tkinter, pyautogui,etc

Here are all the documentation you will need for them:

pyautogui:https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

tkinter : https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

other GUIs:  https://towardsdatascience.com/top-10-python-gui-frameworks-for-developers-adca32fbe6fc

Hopefully this helped you in any way and feel free to ask questions im always online here :)